# Using the zoom and pan functionality of d3

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to use the pan/zoom ability of d3 to draw boxes on the screen so that when you click on a box a new box appears and shifts the rest of the boxes to the right so that the new box is on the center of the canvas. The panning would allow me to scroll through all the boxes I've drawn.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUTBE/1/

And here is my code for initializing the zoom/pan: 
    svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

```
function redraw() {
    d3.select(".canvas").attr("transform",
        "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" 
        + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

And here is my code for drawing the boxes:

```
function drawBox(x, y) {
    var boxGroup = canvas.append("g");
    boxGroup.append("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("fill", function () {
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            if (i === 1) return "red";
            else if (i === 2) return "blue";
           else if (i === 3) return "yellow";
           else return "green";
        })
        .on("click", function () {
            counter++;
            d3.select(".canvas")
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr('transform', "translate(300,0)");
         drawBox(x - counter * 120, y);
        });
}
```

I have multiple problems with this fiddle, but two of my main concerns is:

1) How do I make it so that when I click on a new box a second time the boxes move accordingly (i.e. when I click on the box initially the old box shifts to the right and a new box appears, but when I click on the new box, the older boxes doesnn't shift to the right).

2)Why is it that when I click on the new box, the newer box has a big spacing between it? (only happens after trying to put 3 boxes on the screen).

Thanks any hints are appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using the standard update behaviour (i.e. redraw the boxes at the new positions) instead of using zoom/pan. In particular, your pan is dependent on the position of the cursor, which, if I understood you correctly, is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here around `transform`. The `transform` attribute is static, not cumulative, for a single element - so setting `.attr('transform', "translate(300,0)")` more than once will have no effect after the first time. It also looks like your placement logic for the new boxes is off.

The positioning logic required here is pretty straightforward if you take a step back (assuming I understand what you're trying to do):

1. Every time a new box is added, the frame all boxes are in moves right 120px, so it needs a `x`-translation of `120 * counter`.
2. New boxes need to be offset from the new frame position, so they need an `x` setting of `-120 * counter`.
3. Zoom needs to take the current canvas offset into account.

(1) above can be done in your click handler:

```
canvas
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + (offset * counter) + ",0)");
```

(2) is pretty easily applied to the `g` element you're wrapping boxes in:

```
var boxGroup = canvas.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-offset * counter)  + ',0)');
```

(3) can be added to your `redraw` handler:

```
function redraw() {
    var translation = d3.event.translate,
        newx = translation[0] + offset * counter,
        newy = translation[1];
    canvas.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + newx + "," + newy + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/p3m8A/

Comment: Is there a way to fix the zooming so that you actually zoom where the cursor is?

Comment: I *think* you can do this by setting [zoom.translate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-translate) to the mouse position on zoom start - not tested, though.